# Javscript push method old elements from state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one react component. In the component, I have one button. Using the button, I am pushing data in one array, but the problem is that the old data is removed.i need to remove item,if item is already present there

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
const Home = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const checkboxClick = (item) => {
    const newItems = [...items];
    const index = newItems.findIndex((i) => i._id === item._id);
    console.log(index);
    if (index === -1) {
      newItems.push(item);
    } else {
      newItems.splice(index, 1);
    }

    setItems(newItems);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <button onClick={() => checkboxClick(item)}>Add</button>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: You should try using the splice method like this: newItems.splice(index, 1, item) or you can just remove the else statement because it doesn't seem like you're adding anything extra in item

Comment: You are removing one item from an array by using [`newItems.splice(index, 1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).